# Decompress Action Filter before action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, compression

I wrote an action filter that does compression for the response of some actions.

I'm wanting to write a DecompressRequest attribute also. There are a request or 2 that could be fairly large from the sender that I would like to optionally compress on their end. Is there a way to like OnActionExecuted to inject some code that would detect if it is compressed -> decompress it then submit it to the normal MVC route parsing mechanisms?

I'm just trying to findout where to put my code and how to inject it into MVC, don't need anyone to write the decompression code for me.

Comment: MVC is server side code. Your cant _compress on their end_ - you have no access to there device, and cannot control what they send to the server.

Comment: I have control of the client also in this scenario so that is a non-issue

Comment: No you don't. The clients browser runs in a sandbox.

Comment: This isn't running inside a browser, I'm using an ApiController to do REST calls between IOT and desktop clients.

Comment: The client and server are not connected! You have no idea what is sent by the client until you actually receive it in the request.

Comment: right .. but if I detect a content header or specific formatting I could parse that. Like how on the response currently if I see the Content-Encoding gzip I can decompress from server to client, there is no reason I couldn't do the same from client to server.

Literally the only thing preventing me is knowing where to hook in my code. Some of these applications will use satellite and keeping data communications small at the expense of processor time is definitely worth it and often a speed increase because the travel time is such a bottle neck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an ApiController example of what works, you'd probably have to structure it differently for a normal controller since ApiController requires the parameters to be a bit different for posts. Definitely not 'impossible' as others claimed.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;


namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class DecompressRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private bool IsRequestCompressed(HttpActionContext message)
        {
            foreach(var encoding in message.Request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding)
            {
                if(encoding.Equals("gzip",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if(actionContext.Request.Method.Method == "POST" && actionContext.ActionArguments.Count == 1 && IsRequestCompressed(actionContext))
            {
                Stream stream = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().WaitAndUnwrapException();

                if (stream != null)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream decompressed = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (GZipStream compression = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {
                            int amount;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //Stupid stream doesn't start at beginning for some reason
                            while ((amount = compression.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                decompressed.Write(buffer, 0, amount);
                        }

                        string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed.ToArray());
                        foreach (HttpParameterDescriptor parameter in actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters())
                        {
                            actionContext.ActionArguments[parameter.ParameterName] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, parameter.ParameterType);
                        }                                 
                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```